2005 Lexus RX330 Engine Overheating
I just replaced my car’s engine air filter after a very long time. After I replaced it and started driving, I noticed that my car’s engine temperature went to high (as seen in the picture).

This has never happened before and I don’t think I damaged anything but I guess it’s possible. I’d also had a recent oil change about 2 weeks ago at Valvoline where they had trouble getting the oil filter on but said they got it on at the end.
Any tips on what might be going on? A quick google search suggests it could be anything from a coolant leak to leaking oil to faulty radiator.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
